# When does a polynomial over a field define an injective function?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

In the specific case of algebraically closed fields, the only injective polynomials are the linear ones. Finite fields are also fairly easy to describe since they effectively reduce down to looking at polynomials with degree at most $q-1$ and can be built out of translations of $1-x^{q-1}$ as a basis. In the general case I have worked out a partial result that generates a family of infinitely many solutions, and suspect it might be extended to generate all solutions.

First, we consider monomials. For a monomial to be injective, $x^n=y^n$ implies $x=y$. We can assume neither of them is $0$ and divide through by $y^n$ and substitute $z=\frac{x}{y}$ to get $z^n=1$. Our condition of injectivity now means $z=1$, so we have shown that $x^n$ is injective so long as the field does not have a root of unity $\zeta \ne 1$ of order dividing $n$.

Now because injective functions are closed under composition, translation, and scaling by nonzero constants, we can construct infinitely many polynomials that are injective by composing polynomials of the form $ax^n+b$ with the constraint on $n$ that there exists no $\zeta \ne 1$ with $\zeta^n=1$.

Some nice consequences of this (as a sanity check) are that in $\mathbb{R}$ only odd degree polynomials can be injective and characteristic $p$ fields have no root of unity of order $p$ and so $x^p$ is injective.

Unfortunately this is not enough to generate all injective polynomial functions, for instance $x^3+x \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ can not be constructed in the form $a(x+b)^3+c$. Perhaps there are other operations we can use to extend composition, translation, and scaling so that we get the complete set of injective polynomial functions, or maybe there is some other way to characterize them altogether?

---

Edit2: The proof below is obviously wrong, the lower bound on the limit won't work that way, but I think it can be fixed. Maybe it will inspire ideas in the mean time.

Edit: Taking what Dionel Jaime suggested, I believe I was able to generalize it further. Suppose we have the fields $K \subseteq L$ with a metric induced by an absolute value on $L$ that restricts to $K$ where we have $K$ dense in $L$. Then $f(x)$ is injective in $K[x]$ iff $f(x)$ is injective in $L[x]$.

The proof is obvious in one direction. So for the other, take $f(x)$ injective in $K[x]$. Since it's injective we must have that $|f(x)-f(y)|>0$ for all $x \ne y \in K$. For the sake of contradiction, let's suppose that we have $f(X)-f(Y)=0$ for $X \ne Y \in L$. By density of $K\subseteq L$ we have that we can write $X,Y$ as limits of elements $x,y$ of $K$.
$$0=|f(X)-f(Y)| = \lim_{x,y\to X,Y} |f(x)-f(y)| > 0 $$

So we have reached a contradiction.

The main corollary I have in mind for this proof was to replace $L$ with $\mathbb{Q}_p$ or any finite p-adic field extension and $K$ with $\mathbb{Q}$ or some other finite p-adic extension. A sort of "local global" knee-jerk reaction. I think this proof can be improved (if it contains no mistake) to more general cases, but my topology is lacking.

Comment: Using derivatives could be useful to characterize them. Certainly over any extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and finite fields.

Comment: If $q \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, then $q$ is injective on $\mathbb{Q}$ iff $q$ is injective on $\mathbb{R}$. One direction is obvious. For the other direction, if $q$ is injective on $\mathbb{Q}$ then it's strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. If you're a continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and you're strictly increasing on the rationals, then you're strictly increasing everywhere. Same with strictly decreasing obviously.

Comment: The same proof works if $\mathb{Q}$ is repalced with any extension of it. So to characterize when a polynomial is injective over any subfield of $\mathbb{R}$, it suffices to see if it's injective as a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.